# My Bot Missing Permission module not working discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

The error module is BotMissionPermissions. I made an error to handle it but it's not sending it. I have removed the permission of my bot which is `ban_members`. The main problem is, it's not sending the error message in discord. it should send in discord like `I don't have permission to perform this command`. if you understand please help!

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@commands.bot_has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, *, reason=None):
    if not member:
        await ctx.send("**Please specify a `user`.**")
        return
    if reason==None:
        return await ctx.send("**Please include a** **`valid reason`.**")

    if member == ctx.message.author:
        return await ctx.send("**You cannot ban** **`yourself`**.")
    await member.ban(reason=None)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"****Banned**** **`{member}`** **for the following reason :** **`{reason}` **")
    await member.send(f"you have been banned from: {ctx.guild.name}")

@ban.error
async def banerror(ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, commands.errors.CommandInvokeError):
        await ctx.send("**I don't have the permsission `ban members`.**")

@ban.error
async def banerrogr(ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("**I don't have the permission `ban members`.**")

@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        embed=discord.Embed(color=0xff8800)
        embed.add_field(name="Access denied", value="You do not have permission to ban members :no_entry:", inline=True)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Try comparing it to `commands.errors.BotMissingPermissions`

Comment: add `raise error` inside your error handler to raise the error if you aren't catching it

Comment: You can also `print(error)` to see exactly which error you are getting, maybe you are getting a different error therefore, no message is sent.

Comment: None of these worked and btw would you consider a code instead?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this program works for you

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@commands.bot_has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, *, reason=None):
    if not member:
        await ctx.send("**Please specify a `user`.**")
        return
    if reason==None:
        return await ctx.send("**Please include a** **`valid reason`.**")

    if member == ctx.message.author:
        return await ctx.send("**You cannot ban** **`yourself`**.")
    await member.ban(reason=None)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"****Banned**** **`{member}`** **for the following reason :** **`{reason}` **")
    await member.send(f"you have been banned from: {ctx.guild.name}")

@ban.error
async def banerror(ctx, error):
    error = getattr(error, "original", error) 
    if isinstance(error, discord.Forbidden):
        return await ctx.send("**I don't have the permsission `ban members`.**")

@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        embed=discord.Embed(color=0xff8800)
        embed.add_field(name="Access denied", value="You do not have permission to ban members :no_entry:", inline=True)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```